# What is the Maven dependency for com.amazonaws.services.textract?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

AWS has recently released (28 th Nov 2018) some new APIs. Textract is one of those but still couldn't find a proper document explaining it. Referring to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/index.html#lang/en_us) AWS document . For JAVA there are some dependencies related to textract. Searched for jars and maven dependencies but couldn't find anything.
Any idea on this ?

> import com.amazonaws.services.textract.*

Comment: You can put a concrete class name into the search.maven.org class name search.

Comment: It appears to be in preview and you have to sign up for it: https://pages.awscloud.com/textract-preview.html

Comment: i think they have not introduced the class in their api yet i could not find it in sdk https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2 also the examples are for boto3 library only if language is not an issue for it try it with python

Answer (score 0):

The [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/textract-dg.pdf) says that the preview Java SDK can be downloaded from here:

`s3://amazon-textract-preview/AWSTextractJavaClient-1.11.x.jar`

and the Javadocs:

`s3://amazon-textract-preview/TextractJavaDoc.zip`

Answer (score 0):

This [pom.xml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-textract-pom.xml.html) will help you for AWS textract.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>aws.example.textract</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-textract-examples</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Amazon Textract Examples</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.534</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-textract</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```